# How to exclude a set of packages when using "apt-get remove" with a wild card?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, apt, wildcards

I am trying to use `sudo apt-get remove --purge` to remove all "php7.*" packages however I want to exclude "php7.0*" packages. I have tried;
`sudo apt-get -y remove --purge php7.[^php7.0]*` but didn't work I tried a lot of other similar solutions suggested but non has worked in fact it specifically removes the packages that I want to be excluded. I would really appreciate it if someone solves this puzzle for me.

'Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS'

```
~$ dpkg -l | grep php7
ii  php7.0-cli                          7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.0-common                       7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.0-curl                         7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-fpm                          7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.0-gd                           7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.0-imap                         7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        IMAP module for PHP
ii  php7.0-intl                         7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.0-json                         7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.0-ldap                         7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        LDAP module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mbstring                     7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mcrypt                       7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        libmcrypt module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mysql                        7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-opcache                      7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.0-readline                     7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.0-xml                          7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-zip                          7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        Zip module for PHP
ii  php7.1                              7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.1-bcmath                       7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        Bcmath module for PHP
ii  php7.1-bz2                          7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        bzip2 module for PHP
ii  php7.1-cli                          7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.1-common                       7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.1-curl                         7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-fpm                          7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.1-gd                           7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.1-intl                         7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.1-json                         7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mbstring                     7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.1-opcache                      7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.1-readline                     7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.1-xml                          7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-zip                          7.1.33-16+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        Zip module for PHP
ii  php7.2                              7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.2-bcmath                       7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Bcmath module for PHP
ii  php7.2-bz2                          7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        bzip2 module for PHP
ii  php7.2-cli                          7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.2-common                       7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.2-curl                         7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.2-fpm                          7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.2-gd                           7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.2-intl                         7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.2-json                         7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.2-mbstring                     7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.2-opcache                      7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.2-readline                     7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.2-xml                          7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.2-zip                          7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Zip module for PHP
ii  php7.3                              7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.3-bcmath                       7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Bcmath module for PHP
ii  php7.3-bz2                          7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        bzip2 module for PHP
ii  php7.3-cli                          7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.3-common                       7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.3-curl                         7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.3-fpm                          7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.3-gd                           7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.3-intl                         7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.3-json                         7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.3-mbstring                     7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.3-opcache                      7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.3-readline                     7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.3-xml                          7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.3-zip                          7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Zip module for PHP
```

'Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS'

```
~$ dpkg -l | grep php7
ii  php-common                            2:69+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3                 all          Common files for PHP packages
ii  php7.0                                7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.0-bcmath                         7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        Bcmath module for PHP
ii  php7.0-bz2                            7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        bzip2 module for PHP
ii  php7.0-cli                            7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.0-common                         7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.0-curl                           7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-fpm                            7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.0-gd                             7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.0-intl                           7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.0-json                           7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mbstring                       7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.0-opcache                        7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.0-readline                       7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.0-xml                            7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-zip                            7.0.33-29+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                   amd64        Zip module for PHP
ii  php7.1-cli                            7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.1-common                         7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.1-curl                           7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-fpm                            7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.1-gd                             7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.1-imap                           7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        IMAP module for PHP
ii  php7.1-intl                           7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.1-json                           7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.1-ldap                           7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        LDAP module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mbstring                       7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mcrypt                         7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        libmcrypt module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mysql                          7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-opcache                        7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.1-readline                       7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.1-xml                            7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-zip                            7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Zip module for PHP
ii  php7.2                                7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.2-bcmath                         7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Bcmath module for PHP
ii  php7.2-bz2                            7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        bzip2 module for PHP
ii  php7.2-cli                            7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.2-common                         7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.2-curl                           7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.2-fpm                            7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.2-gd                             7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.2-intl                           7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.2-json                           7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.2-mbstring                       7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.2-opcache                        7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.2-readline                       7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.2-xml                            7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.2-zip                            7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Zip module for PHP
ii  php7.3                                7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.3-bcmath                         7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Bcmath module for PHP
ii  php7.3-bz2                            7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        bzip2 module for PHP
ii  php7.3-cli                            7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.3-common                         7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.3-curl                           7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.3-fpm                            7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.3-gd                             7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.3-intl                           7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.3-json                           7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.3-mbstring                       7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.3-opcache                        7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.3-readline                       7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.3-xml                            7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.3-zip                            7.3.19-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        Zip module for PHP
```

Comment: What are the version numbers of the other `php` packages installed on the system?

Comment: its php7.0 on ubuntu. There are other PHP versions and the packages which I want to remove all of them but exclude php7.0 packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $(
    dpkg -l | awk '$1 == "ii" && /php7/ && !/php7\.0/{print $2}'
)
```

To pass variables to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), use `-v` switch:

```
EXCLUDE_VERSION='php7.0'
awk -v exv="$EXCLUDE_VERSION" '$1 == "ii" && /php7/ && $2 !~ exv{print $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks, Gilles for your suggested solution. Your code works perfectly as it is, but I now want to inject the exclusion into the 'dpkg' command as a variable. e.g I have tried; 
`EXCLUDE_VERSION="7.0";`
`sudo apt-get remove --purge $(
    dpkg -l | awk '$1 == "ii" && /php7/ && !/php${EXCLUDE_VERSION}/{print $2}'
);`
But I wasn't able to get it working. If you can please advise on how to inject the exclusion string as a variable you will make my day. Thanks!

Comment: Post edited accordingly. Have you testes @Martin Konrad solution ? Looks appropriate

Comment: I have tested your code on 'Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS' and its nor working, the dpkg returns also the excluded packages. However, it works for on 'Ubuntu 16.04.4' LTS. It includes package from all PHP versions that exists in the system.

Comment: Have you tested @Martin Konrad solution ? Is it working ?

Comment: I have also tried @Martin solution that one only works on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: Your solution is much safer but if I can make it work on both versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you post `dpkg -l | grep php7` both for 16.04.6 and 16.04.4 by [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/594702/edit) your original post ?

Comment: Can't reproduce. My awk filter works for both 16.04.4 & 16.04.6 outputs. Can you show how you run the command ?

Comment: This finally worked for me
`sudo apt-get -y remove --purge $(
        dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i "php7.*" | grep -i -v "php${PHP_VER}"
);`

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression doesn't look correct. It is matching package names containing (not necessarily starting with) "php7" plus one more arbitrary character (".") followed by an arbitrary number of characters which are none of the following: p, h, 7, ., 0.

What you probably want instead is the following regular expression:

```
sudo apt-get -y remove --purge '^php7\.[^0]'
```

This matches "php7." at the beginning (^) of a package name plus any character other than 0. Further characters might follow but we don't need to consider them.